# Is it possible to create a sub-branch in Bazaar?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I need to make a small set of changes to my project, but I want to keep them alongside the main tree - so that I can revert to earlier state after that, and continue working (I want to make a small crippled build of my project). But I do not want to make a full branch of my project.

For example:

```
  ...
   |
  rev 100
   |     \ 
rev 103   rev 101
   |        \
  ...       rev 102
```

And I want to be able to revert to any of these revisions. Is it possible in Bazaar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [bzr-colo plugin](http://launchpad.net/bzr-colo) for this:

```
cd your-branch
# prepare colo workspace
bzr colo-ify
# create a subbranch
bzr switch -b subbbranch
# hack-hack-hack-commit-commit
#now revert back to your main state
bzr switch trunk
# now you want to come back to subbranch
bzr switch subbranch
```

See `bzr help colo` for user manual of bzr-colo.